# Complete Math Equation by Filling Missing Operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, logic, operators

I stumbled upon this programming question. So the question want us to complete the mathematical equation in the input. The operator that can be used are (+, -, *, /, ^, %). Here are some sample.

```
Input : 5 3 8           Output : 5+3=8
Input : 9 27 3          Output : 9=27/3
Input : 5 2 25 , 1 5 2  Output : 5^2=25 , 1=5%2
```

I hope this sample already gives you clear idea about what the question want us to do. If it is not clear, please comment so I can interpret it better.

P.S. It is fine to use any language as long as it is understandable.

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: My initial idea is to replace the space with operators, but I think it does not solve what operators to use in each space. I tried google but found nothing similar. If you know any post similar to this, please send the link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below can find possible answers by brute force permutation.

```js
const qs = ["5 3 8", "9 27 3", "5 2 25", "1 5 2", "3 3 3 30"];
for(const q of qs)
{
  const answers = [];
  for(let n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
  {
    const s = q.replace(/ /g, () => "+-*/^%="[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]);
    if(eval(s.replace(/=/g, "===").replace(/\^/g, "**")) === true && answers.indexOf(s) === -1)
    {
      answers.push(s);
    }
  }
  console.log(`Possible answer ${answers.length === 0 ? "not found (yet)" : answers.join(" or ")}`);
}
```

Comment: When you declare s, can you explain what () => mean and why do you replace = with === and ^ with **?

Comment: `() => 1 + 2` is an _arrow function_ that returns `3` - you can learn more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: In JavaScript the equality (`=`) operator is `===` and the exponentiation (`^`) operator is `**`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to solve these but don't know how try this...

1. Choose the bigger number on one of the sides like in 1 4 7 it would be 7
2. Put an equal to facing the middle. Like 1 4 7 it would be 1 4=7
3. Solve
4. If that doesn't work try the other number

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes that's what I stated in the question. How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorythmic solution that would find **all** possible answers and can be easily translated to any language:

```js
var data = ['2 1 2', '5 3 8', '9 27 3', '5 2 25', '1 5 2', '5 2 25 , 1 5 2'];
var operations = [
  { sign: '+', result: (a,b) => a+b },
  { sign: '-', result: (a,b) => a-b },
  { sign: '*', result: (a,b) => a*b },
  { sign: '/', result: (a,b) => a/b },
  { sign: '^', result: (a,b) => a**b },
  { sign: '%', result: (a,b) => a%b }
];
function check(str) {
  // split string into the array of operands
  var operands = str.trim().split(/\s+/).map(Number);
  // validate array of operands
  if ((operands.length != 3) || operands.includes(NaN)) {
console.log(`invalid input data '${str}'`);
  } else {
console.log(`searching solution for '${str}'`);
// here is the main logic start
for (i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) { // loop through all defined operations
  // checking for 'a <sign> b = c' expression
  if (operations[i].result(operands[0],operands[1]) == operands[2]) {
    console.log(`found a solution: ${operands[0]}${operations[i].sign}${operands[1]}=${operands[2]}`);
  }
  // checking for 'a = b <sign> c' expression
  if (operands[0] == operations[i].result(operands[1],operands[2])) {
    console.log(`found a solution: ${operands[0]}=${operands[1]}${operations[i].sign}${operands[2]}`);
  }
}
  }
}
data.forEach(check);
```

However it accepts data only in `operand1 operand2 operand3` form so it wouldn't solve the last data piece. It is possible to write an additional splitter which would check and split source string to substrings by coma, but I left it to you. This is an example how the main task could be solved.

If you don't understand arrow functions, here is pre-ES6 code:

```
var operations = [
  { sign: '+', result: function(a,b){ return a+b } },
  { sign: '-', result: function(a,b){ return a-b } },
  { sign: '*', result: function(a,b){ return a*b } },
  { sign: '/', result: function(a,b){ return a/b } },
  { sign: '^', result: function(a,b){ return a**b } },
  { sign: '%', result: function(a,b){ return a%b } }
];
```